# when a software run for a long time, it crash

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I have finish my game project, using `cocos2d-x`, develop with Visual studio 2010, and deploy it to android.

It work perfectly, well almost.

I run it on android, and write a small AI to play my game, But after a long unpredictable time,maybe two hours, maybe one morning, maybe one day, it quit with not obvious reason!

Someone remind me that it maybe due to some annoying small memory leak, when AI play it over and over again, those memory leak accumulated and crash my game.

If that maybe the reason, then how am I supposed to debug, find out what or where in program cause the problem?

Any good tools to debug memory leak?

I know one visual memory leak; any good tools to monitor memory while my game is running?

Comment: I have no idea what cocos2d-x is, but for pure Android, LeakCanary (https://github.com/square/leakcanary) is pretty awesome.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, but I debug in vs;

Comment: not more replay? any one have any thought about how to make software more stable? What aspect we really need to concert about?

Comment: You could use the NVIDIA Nsight Tegra Plugin for Visual Studio or take the Device Monitor from Android SDK.